# Firefox issues when displaying SVG (Firefox 55.0.3)

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg, issuu

Firefox won't display the SVG book covers properly ...

http://new.images.hindawi.org/kalimat/covers/svg/270x360/c/24972860.svg

Compare the link above in Firefox and Chrome.
It used to be displayed just fine in Firefox, but I think something went wrong with the latest update.

If any one know a solution to this issue it would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check your browser inspector, than you will see an error:

> There is an SVG  reference chain which is too long in this
>   document, which will prevent the document rendering correctly.

Inside your SVG image there are many of them, looking like:

```
<path clip-path="url(#SVGID_68_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="..." />
```

Either create less accurate SVG (less details), or create it some other way.

Since it is rendered well in webkit browsers, than maybe you can use [wkhtmltoimage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wkhtmltoimage) to convert it server side to PNG or JPG.

Comment: Could that be just a bug in the latest Firefox update? Since it was working just fine in the previous version, I even tested it in Browserstack.

Comment: Bug or not a bug, you have to solve the issue, I offered you two solutions.